# Extending Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, webserver, database-schema

I have two apps in my project, app1 and app2.
In app1 I have two models called Task and Job.
I want to add new feature to these two models, I want to add category to them.
But its more complicated then just a new field and app2 is mainly responsible for estimation of the category, so I created new model in the app2 as below:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    CAT1 = 1
    CAT2 = 2
    OTHER = 6
    UNKNOWN = 7
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (CAT1, "Cat1"),
        (CAT2, "Cat2"),
        (OTHER, "Other"),
        (UNKNOWN, "Unknown"),
    )
    auto_category = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=UNKNOWN)
    user_category = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=UNKNOWN)
    modify_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey("app1.User", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='category_creator', blank=True, null=True)
```

Also I want every Task and Job object to have a default category as soon as it is created so I don't have to deal with None values on the frontend, "Unknown" value should be a default value so I created below function in app2/utils.py:

```
def create_default_category():
    new_category = Category.objects.create()
    return new_category.pk
```

And then I added OneToOneField relation to my Task and Job models in the app1 as well as default value:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    # Some already existing fields
    category = models.OneToOneField('app2.Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='task_category', default=create_default_category)


class Job(models.Model):
    # Some already existing fields
    category = models.OneToOneField('app2.Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='job_category', default=create_default_category)
```

But all of above doesn't seem to work as I expected.
When I tried to run migration of app1 the is an error saying:

```
(venv) C:\project>python manage.py migrate app1
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: app1
Running migrations:
  Applying app1.0003_auto_20230828_1538...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: could not create unique index "app1_task_category_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (category_id)=(1) is duplicated.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 232, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 110, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 447, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "app1_task_category_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (category_id)=(1) is duplicated.
```

There are a lot of already existing Task and Job model objects in my db, there is no object of Category model in the db, the table is literally empty.

**Does anyone know what could potentially cause this problem? Or whats the proper solution for such such problem?**

I already ran the migration for app2 and the table is normally created in the db, I am also able to manually create new Category objects in the db.
I tried to reset the indexes in the app2.Category table in the database but it didn't change anything.
I reverted and ran the migration again - it also didn't help.

I am also aware that I could create an abstract model class in the app1 and just inherit it in the Task and Job models - is it better solution?

I just thought that since Category is more connected with app2 it would be reasonable to put the code in the app2/models.py file.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a `OneToOneField`

```
category = models.OneToOneField('app2.Category',
```

This is going to create a unique DB index for that field, because every value should be a distinct record. This is the index for which you are getting `IntegrityError`

As to why, I suspect it's the migration. What you probably want to do is a 3 part migration here:

1. Add the fields without the `default` values and allow null
2. Populate the fields manually with a custom migration
3. Once the fields are correctly populated, add the `default` setting for new values.